# WinRT Listview Scrolling Not Working in Grid

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-runtime, grid, windows-phone-8.1

Okay so I have a parent grid, where three other grid resides in it. Problem is I've a Listview inside the last one. In this grid the listview items scrolling doesn't work. But if I move the same listview in the middle grid the scrolling works exactly as i want. What am I missing here? How can I make this Listview Scrolling work in the last grid. Here is the code snippets. TIA

```
<Grid  x:Name="Container" Background="Transparent">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HambugerMenuStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="HamburgerCloseState"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="HamburgerOpenState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="380" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.GlobalOffsetX)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="480" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.GlobalOffsetX)" Storyboard.TargetName="HamburerPane" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ManualDataPanelStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="ManualDataPanelCloseState"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="ManualDataPanelOpenState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.GlobalOffsetY)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-380" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.GlobalOffsetX)" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-460" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.GlobalOffsetX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ManualDataPane" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid x:Name="HamburerPane"
          Margin="-480,0,0,0">
        <Grid.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection/>
        </Grid.Projection>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection/>
        </Grid.Projection>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>

        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <maps:MapControl Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" x:Name="MapControl"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <!--<maps:MapItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MapControlDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            </maps:MapItemsControl>-->
        </maps:MapControl>

        <Slider x:Name="RotationSlider" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="360" Value="{Binding Heading, ElementName=MapControl, Mode=TwoWay}" ></Slider>
        <Slider x:Name="PitchSlider" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical" Maximum="65" Value="{Binding DesiredPitch, ElementName=MapControl, Mode=TwoWay}" ></Slider>
    </Grid>


    <Grid x:Name="ManualDataPane"
          Margin="0,0,-480,0">
        <Grid.Projection>
            <PlaneProjection/>
        </Grid.Projection>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Origins}" Height ="{Binding ElementName=ManualDataPane, Path=ActualHeight}" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <expaControl:ExpanderControl Width="400"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Intersections}"
                    HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomHeaderTemplate}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomItemTemplate}" IsExpanded="False" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderControlStyle}" ExpanderTemplate="{StaticResource CustomExpanderTemplate}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

This three grids are inside a parent grid. The grid.projection are just for animating the grid like the hamburger menu. No problem there.

Comment: Could you check the ActualHight of your ListView at runtime? Also, that hight binding could cause problems. It should have the same height as it's parent, event without that ElementName Binding.

Answer (score 0):

The Row definition for the grid is Auto for the Row it is in. If a listview is put in a row with auto it will not scroll you must use either *,1*,2* etc or a fixed height.

Comment: i've set a fixed height on the grid...it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I found recently that when I put a ListView in a Container with `<PlaneProjection/>` the scrolling stopped working. Taking the PlaneProjection off allowed the ListView to scroll again. Is this your problem? I'm looking for a solution myself at the moment.